Joint measurability of strongly continuous vector-valued function
Suppose that $\mathbb{R}\to L^2(\mathbb{R}),$ $t\mapsto g_t$ is continuous. (Under which additional assumptions) is it true that $G\colon \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $G(t,x):=\widetilde{g_t}(x)$ is measurable? Here $\widetilde{g_t}$ is a representative of $g_t\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$
I know the argument to deduce measurability of a function $h\colon \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ for which $h(t, \cdot)$ is measurable for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and for which $h(\cdot, x)$ is $\textit{pointwise continuous}$ for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (one simply approximates $h$ by simple functions using the continuity w.r.t. the first variable). However, I have the impression that matters are more complicated if I only assume continuity w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm.
I would appreciate any hints.

The main result in "The measurability of a stochastic process of second order and its linear space," Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 47 (1975)  467–475, by S. Cambanis, implies a given selection $(\tilde g_t)_{t\in\Bbb R}$ of representatives admits a measurable modification $(\hat g_t)_{t\in\Bbb R}$. Then $G(t,x):=\hat g_t(x)$ is what you need. (The hypotheses of Cambanis' result involve the measurability of $(s,t)\mapsto \Bbb E(g_sg_t)$ and a separability condition; these are more than satisfied under your continuity condition.)

Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for! :)
